# How can I pass an array of values to the parent window of the iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

How can I pass an array of values ​​to the parent window of the iframe?

```
<input type="text"  name="relate_name" id="" value="<%=vo2.getRelate_name() %>" style="width: 100px;"/>
<input type="text"  name="relate_name" id="" value="<%=vo2.getRelate_name() %>" style="width: 100px;"/>
<input type="text"  name="relate_name" id="" value="<%=vo2.getRelate_name() %>" style="width: 100px;"/>    <--iframe 

 <form name="writeform" method="post" action="incidentInsert.jsp?incident_id=<%=vo1.getIncident_id()%>" target="aaFrame">

 <iframe  width="600" height="180" name="aaFrame" id="aaFrame">
 </iframe>
 </form>
```

Comment: `parent.document` 된다

Comment: `top.postMessage()` can pass arrays, not just strings